# i can't make WorkbookFactory in ZK working

Tags: apache-poi, zk

I'm a newbie in zk programing.. and right now I'm using Eclipse Indigo to develop it.
I'm trying to import Excel `.xlsx` file, but it's not working.. I get error message `org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory`

here is my `.zul` code

```
 <?page title="import excel" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?><zk>
<window id="win" title="import excel" border="normal">
    <listbox  width="700px" id="box" mold="paging" pageSize="50" sizedByContent="true" span="true">

    </listbox>

    <button label="Load Excel to listview" upload="true,maxsize=300">
        <attribute name="onUpload"><![CDATA[

            import java.io.File;
            import org.zkoss.io.Files;
            import org.zkoss.util.media.Media;

            String path = Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getWebApp().getRealPath("/");
            //alert(path);
            Media media = event.getMedia();

            Files.copy(new File(path+ "upload\\" + media.getName()), media.getStreamData());
            com.function.ZKextend zke=new com.function.ZKextend();
            //zke.ImportExcelProd(win,"box",media);
            zke.ImportExcel(win,"box",media);


        ]]></attribute>
    </button>
    <separator />
</window>
</zk>
```

and this is my function to import the excel `.xlsx` file..

```
public void ImportExcel(Window nmWindow, String nmListbox, Media media) throws Exception{


    /* We should now load excel objects and loop through the worksheet data */
    FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new java.io.File("")+Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getWebApp().getRealPath("/")+"upload/"+media.getName());
    Workbook my_xls_workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(input_document);
    Sheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = my_worksheet.iterator(); 

    Listbox list = (Listbox) nmWindow.getFellow(nmListbox);
    list.getItems().removeAll(list.getItems());

    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next(); 
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        Listitem li = new Listitem();

        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()) { 
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: //handle string columns
                    cell.getStringCellValue();          
                    li.setValue(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    li.appendChild(new Listcell(cell.getStringCellValue()));
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: //handle double data
                    cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    li.setValue(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    li.appendChild(new Listcell(String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue())));
                    break;
            }


        }
        list.appendChild(li);
    }

}
```

And I already added **poi-3.8, poi-ooxml-3.8, poi-ooxml-schema-3.8,xmlbean-2.3** to my java build path library through `add external JAR` button in the project properties.

Is there anything that I miss so I get this error? Please help me, I'm really desperate here..
Thanks..

Comment: See if this example will help you? http://zkframeworkhint.blogspot.in/2013/05/zk-upload-image-or-image-binding-in.html

Comment: What's the full error / stacktrace?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, thanks for responding my question, the error in the console will be like this :

Aug 07, 2013 12:14:55 AM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError:1348
SEVERE: >>java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory
>>java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
>> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>> at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)

Comment: i already solve the problem.. thx Gagravarr :D

Comment: If you have solved the question, please post the answer and accept that, so that it will no more remain as an unanswered question. Or if you are not thinking the answer as relevant to share, or may be because of small silly mistake, you can delete the question if you want.